# How can I implement the merge functionality for 2048

Tags: javascript, algorithm, oop, ecmascript-6, 2048

I am trying to implement [the game 2048](https://play2048.co/) using JavaScript. I am using a two-dimensional array to represent the board. For each row, it is represented using an array of integers.

Here I am focused on implementing the merge left functionality i.e. the merge that happens after the user hits left on their keyboard.

Here are a set of test cases that I came up with

```js
const array1 = [2, 2, 2, 0] //  [4,2,0,0]
const array2 = [2, 2, 2, 2] // [4,4,0,0]
const array3 = [2, 0, 0, 2] // [4,0,0,0]
const array4 = [2, 2, 4, 16] // [4,4,16,0]
```

The commented part is the expected results after `merge left` happened.

Here is my attempt

```js
const arrays = [
  [2, 2, 2, 0], //  [4,2,0,0]
  [2, 2, 2, 2], // [4,4,0,0]
  [2, 0, 0, 2], // [4,0,0,0]
  [2, 2, 4, 16] // [4,4,16,0]
];

function mergeLeft(array) {
  let startIndex = 0
  let endIndex = 1
  while (endIndex < array.length) {
    if (array[startIndex] === array[endIndex]) {
      array[startIndex] = array[startIndex] + array[endIndex]
      array[endIndex] = 0
      startIndex++
    }
    endIndex++
  }
  return shift(array, 'left')
}

function shift(array, dir) {
  if (dir === 'left') {
    for (let i = 0; i < array.length - 1; i++) {
      if (array[i] === 0) {
        [array[i], array[i + 1]] = [array[i + 1], array[i]]
      }
    }
  }
  // omitting when dir === 'right', 'up', 'down' etc.
  return array
}

arrays.forEach(a => console.log(mergeLeft(a)));
```

So the idea here is that I merged the array and then shift the non-zero items to the left.

My current solution is buggy for this particular case - when the array is `[2, 2, 2, 2]`, the output is `[4,2,2,0]` when the expected output is `[4,4,0,0]`

I know that my implementation is not elegant either. So I would love to see how this can be implemented in a (much) better way.

By the way I found on code review stack exchange there is a python implementation that seems to be working. However, I don't really know Python nor functional programming paradigm. I would appreciate it if someone can [take a look at it](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/91441/functional-programming-in-python-2048-merge-functions) and see if how this can be translated into JavaScript

Comment: you are not handling the startindex correctly ... it should be incremented also if no merge occur ... the only case where it is not incremented is when you processing empty space

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think a recursive version is simplest here:

```js
const zeroFill = xs => 
  xs .concat ([0, 0, 0, 0]) .slice (0, 4)

const shift = ([n0, n1, ...ns]) =>
  n0 == undefined
    ? []
  : n0 == 0
    ? shift ([n1, ...ns])
  : n1 == 0
    ? shift ([n0, ...ns])
  : n0 == n1
    ? [n0 + n1, ... shift (ns)]
  : [n0, ...shift ([n1, ... ns])]

const shiftLeft = (ns) => 
  zeroFill (shift (ns))

const arrays = [[2, 2, 2, 0], [2, 2, 2, 2], [2, 0, 0, 2], [2, 2, 4, 16], [0, 8, 2, 2], [0, 0, 0, 0]];

arrays .forEach (
  a => console.log(`${JSON .stringify (a)}: ${JSON .stringify (shiftLeft (a))}`)
)
```

Our basic `shift` is wrapped with `zeroFill`, which adds trailing zeros to the the array, to make it four long.

The main function is `shift`, which does a shift-left of a row, but if I were to build a complete 2048, I would used this for all shifts, simply translating the directions to the indices required.  It works like this:

- If our array is empty, we return an empty array
- If the first value is zero, we ignore it and continue with the rest of the array
- If the second value is zero, we remove it and recur with the remainder (including the first value)
- If the first two values are equal, we combine them for the first spot and recur on the remainder
- Otherwise, we keep the first value, and then recur on everything else (including the second value)

Although we could remove the wrapper, merging the zero-filling into the main function, so that, for instance in the second case, instead of returning `shift([n1, ...ns])` we would return `zeroFill(shift([n1, ...ns]))`.  But that would mean calling the zero-fill several times for no good reason.

## Update

A comment asked for clarification on how I would use this for shifting boards in all directions.  Here is my first thought:

```js
// utility functions
const reverse = (xs) => 
  [...xs] .reverse();

const transpose = (xs) => 
  xs [0] .map ((_, i) => xs .map (r => r[i]))

const rotateClockwise = (xs) =>
  transpose (reverse (xs))

const rotateCounter = (xs) => 
  reverse (transpose (xs))

// helper functions
const shift = ([n0, n1, ...ns]) =>
  n0 == undefined
    ? []
  : n0 == 0
    ? shift ([n1, ...ns])
  : n1 == 0
    ? shift ([n0, ...ns])
  : n0 == n1
    ? [n0 + n1, ... shift (ns)]
  : [n0, ... shift ([n1, ... ns])]

const shiftRow = (ns) => 
  shift (ns) .concat ([0, 0, 0, 0]) .slice (0, 4)

// main functions
const shiftLeft = (xs) => 
  xs .map (shiftRow)

const shiftRight = (xs) => 
  xs .map (x => reverse (shiftRow (reverse (x))))

const shiftUp = (xs) =>
  rotateClockwise (shiftLeft (rotateCounter (board)))  

const shiftDown = (xs) =>
  rotateClockwise (shiftRight (rotateCounter (board)))  

// sample data
const board = [[4, 0, 2, 0], [8, 0, 8, 8], [2, 2, 4, 8], [0, 0, 4, 4]]

// demo
const display = (title, xss) => console .log (`----------------------\n${title}\n----------------------\n${xss .map (xs => xs .map (x => String(x).padStart (2, ' ')) .join(' ')).join('\n')}`)

display ('original', board)
display ('original shifted left', shiftLeft (board))
display ('original shifted right', shiftRight (board))
display ('original shifted up', shiftUp (board))
display ('original shifted down', shiftDown (board))
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {max-height: 100% !important; top: 0}
```

We start with function to reverse a copy of an array, and to transpose a grid over the main diagonal (northwest to southeast).  We combine those two in order to create functions to rotate a grid clockwise and counter-clockwise.  Then we include the function discussed above, slightly renamed, and with the zero-fill helper inlined.

Using these we can now write our directional shift function fairly easily.  `shiftLeft` just maps `shiftRow` over the rows.  `shiftRight` first reverses the rows, calls `shiftLeft` and then reverses them again.  `shiftUp` and `shiftDown` rotate the board counter-clockwise call `shiftLeft` and `shiftRight`, respectively, and then rotates the board clockwise.

Note that none of these main functions mutate your data.  Each returns a new board.  That is one of the most important tenets of functional programming: treat data as immutable.

This is not a full 2048 system.  It doesn't randomly add new `2`s or `4`s to the board, nor does it have any notion of a user interface.  But I think it's probably a reasonably solid core for a functional version of the game..

Comment: Hi thanks for the answer! Could you please elaborate a little more on what you meant by " if I were to build a complete 2048, I would used this for all shifts, simply translating the directions to the indices required.". I wonder how you would reuse or tweak the existing shift function to adapt to different directions? Also by the way, since in the game you can also move up or down, do you know how we can implement the shift for up and down as well? I think it is trickier than left and right since the numbers in the same column would be in different arrays

Comment: Added an update explaining how I might use this function in a full 2048 implementation.

Comment: Hi thanks for the update. I think there is a bug in your updated code. So in the `shifted right` example, shouldn't `16  8  0  0` become `0 0 16 8`? also `4  4  8  0` should become `0  0  8  8` right?

Comment: All are shifts from the original board, not one from the other.  I'll edit to make that clear.

Comment: Got it. so I want to perform shifting consecutively I need to pipe(not sure if this is the right word) them like `shiftRight(shiftLeft(board))`? Btw this is so cool! Could you enlighten me on the benefits of using functional programming here instead of traditional oop?

Comment: I expect it would be more like `board = shiftLeft(board); board = shiftRight (board)`.  Or possibly something more functional that simply creates an entirely new game state from the current one.  As to FP vs OOP, I'm afraid that's far too big a discussion.  Even if you don't prefer it, though, you can incorporate it in the small by using simple functions like this to create new game states inside an otherwise mutable world.

Comment: Hi thanks for the reply. I do like functional programming it is just that I am not able to exactly pinpoint the benefit of using it here. one last question, could you elaborate a bit on what you meant by `board = shiftLeft(board); board = shiftRight (board)` so you are reassigning `board` again and again? I thought that is not allowed in functional programming?

Comment: If your system was completely FP, that would not be allowed, but in a hybrid model, you might do something like that.  I wasn't trying to use this to push FP.  It's simply what comes to mind for me.

Comment: impressive, this JS looks like haskell. great answer!

Answer (score 0):

You can try this.

```js
const arrays = [
  [2, 2, 2, 0], //  [4,2,0,0]
  [2, 2, 2, 2], // [4,4,0,0]
  [2, 0, 0, 2], // [4,0,0,0]
  [2, 2, 4, 16] // [4,4,16,0]
];


function shiftLeft(array) {
    op = []
    while(array.length!=0){
        let v1 = array.shift();
        while(v1==0 && array.length>0){
            v1 = array.shift();
        }

        if(array.length==0){
            op.push(v1);
        }else{
            let v2 = array.shift();
            while(v2==0 && array.length>0){
                v2 = array.shift();
            }

            if(v1==v2){
                op.push(v1+v2);
            }else{
                op.push(v1);
                array.unshift(v2);
            }
        }
    }

    while(op.length!=4){
        op.push(0);
    }
  return op
}

arrays.forEach(a => console.log(shiftLeft(a)));
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a function that performs the merge and shift in one loop:

```js
function mergeLeft(array) {
    let startIndex = 0;
    for (let endIndex = 1; endIndex < array.length; endIndex++) {
        if (!array[endIndex]) continue;
        let target = array[startIndex];
        if (!target || target === array[endIndex]) { // shift or merge
            array[startIndex] += array[endIndex];
            array[endIndex] = 0;
        } else if (startIndex + 1 < endIndex) {
            endIndex--; // undo the next for-loop increment
        }
        startIndex += !!target;
    }
    return array;
}

// Your tests:
const arrays = [
  [2, 2, 2, 0], // [4,2,0,0]
  [2, 2, 2, 2], // [4,4,0,0]
  [2, 0, 0, 2], // [4,0,0,0]
  [2, 2, 4, 16] // [4,4,16,0]
];

for (let array of arrays) console.log(...mergeLeft(array));
```

### Explanations

The `for` loop increments the `endIndex` from 1 to 3 included. This index represents a potential value that needs to shift and/or merge.

If that index refers to an empty slot (value is 0), then nothing needs to happen with it, and so we `continue` with the next iteration of the loop.

So now we are in the case where `endIndex` refers to a non-zero value. There are two cases where something needs to happen with that value:

- The value at `startIndex` is zero: in that case the value at `endIndex` must move to `startIndex`
- The value at `startIndex` is equal to that at `endIndex`: in that case the value at `endIndex` must also move to `startIndex`, but adding to it what was already there.

These cases are very similar. In the first case we could even say that the value at `endIndex` is *added* to the one at `startIndex` since the latter is zero. So these two cases are handled in one `if` block.

If we are not in either of these two cases then we know that the value at `startIndex` is non-zero and different from the one at `endIndex`. In that case we should leave the value at `startIndex` unaltered and just move on. However, we should reconsider the value of this same `endIndex` again in the next iteration, as it might need to move still. So that is why we do `endIndex--` so to neutralise the loop's `endIndex++` that will happen one instant later.

There is one case where we *do* want to go to the next `endIndex`: that is when `startIndex` would become equal to `endIndex`: that should never be allowed in this algorithm.

Finally, `startIndex` is incremented when it originally had a non-zero value. However, if it was zero at the start of this iteration, it should be reconsidered in the next iteration of the loop. So then we do not add 1 to it. `startIndex += !!target` is just another way for doing:

```
if (target > 0) startIndex++;
```

Comment: hi could you please describe your algorithm?

Comment: Added a section with explanations.

Comment: Hi thanks for the explanation. Since in the game you can also move up or down, do you know how we can implement the shift for up and down as well? I think it is trickier than left and right since the numbers in the same column would be in different arrays

Comment: Sure, but it is not essentially different; you would just use a fixed first index (to denote the column) and vary `startIndex` and `endIndex` for the second dimension. You should have a go at it. If you cannot make it work, ask a new question about that.

Comment: Thank you for the reply! Just one last question. Is there a way to make this solution easily extensible to `mergeRight`?

Comment: Yes, that is possible. Have a go at it. If you have a problem, ask a question about it. One simple way is to reverse the array, apply mergeLeft and reverse again. But the right way is of course to mirror the iteration and index values.